# Significance of double pointer and triple pointer in this code snippet

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void add(char **p);
void print(char **p);
int cnt=0;
main()
{
  int option;
  char **p=NULL;
while(1)
{
  printf("------MENU-----\n");
  printf("1>input\n 2>print\n3>exit\n");
  printf("enter ur choice\n");
  scanf("%d",&option);getchar();
 switch(option)
 {
    case 1: add(p);
            break;
    case 2: print(p);
            break;
   case 3: return;
   default: printf("Invalid option\n");

 }
}
}
void add(char **p)
{
  int i;
  p=(char**)realloc(p,(cnt+1)*sizeof(char*));
  if(p==NULL)
  {
        printf("Error: memory not available\n");
        return;

  }
  p[cnt]=NULL;
  p[cnt]=(char*)realloc(p[cnt],20*sizeof(char));

  puts("enter a name");
  gets(p[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  printf("cnt=%d\n",cnt);
}
void print(char **p)
{
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<cnt;i++)
  printf("p[%d]=%s\n",i,p[i]);
}
```

In the above code, I am making a database of names. For this I am using dynamic memory allocation. I am allocation memory for 2D-array using array of pointers method. When I am executing this program on **gcc compiler**, I am getting **segmentation fault**. I am not understanding why is it happening?Could you please tell me where the bug is?

Comment: On top of what's already been mentioned in the answers below about variable `p` being local in function `add`, I'm pretty sure that you must initialize `p = malloc(...)` to begin with, since function `realloc` expects (as input argument) a pointer to a memory segment previously allocated with either `malloc` or `realloc`.

Comment: Some hints: use a debugger, consistently indent your code, avoid `gets`, do not cast the return values of `malloc`/`realloc`, `sizeof(char)` is always 1.

Comment: @barakmanos: My C standard says "If `ptr` is a null pointer, the `realloc` function behaves like the `malloc` function." But still, if `print` is called without prior `add`, the pointer is 0.

Comment: @barakmanos - `realloc` can do literally __everything__ which `malloc` and `free` can do (including initial allocations). Which is an argument for never using `realloc` rather than for never using `malloc` or `free`! Whoever designed `realloc` had forgotten about 'do one thing and do it well' as a design principle.

Comment: @AAT `realloc()` may "copy" the contents of memory to another new logical location without changing the physical address for it knows the source will be free'd.  Hence no `memcpy()` need to occur.  How would `malloc()` and `free()` perform this efficient re-allocation?

Comment: `gets(p[cnt]);` is prone to input overflow.  Suggest using `fget(p[cnt], 20, stdin);`.  Note that a `'\n'` may be included near the end of the string.

Comment: @chux - if you happen to be in a situation where that level is optimisation is significant, then the risks associated with `realloc` may be justified, __if__ you can show that it does perform better than `malloc - memcpy - free` for your case. But using it as a reason for __starting__ with `realloc` sounds like premature optimisation to me.

Answer (score 1):

`p` in `main` is handed over to `add` by value. `add` modifies a local copy then, but not the original `p`.

Besides the terrible formatting and everything you need to hand a pointer to your `main`'s `p` to `add`:

```
...

  case 1: add(&p);
...

void add(char ***p)
{
  int i;
  *p = realloc(*p,(cnt+1)*sizeof(char*));
  if(*p==NULL)
  {
        printf("Error: memory not available\n");
        return;

  }
  (*p)[cnt]=NULL;
  (*p)[cnt]=realloc((*p)[cnt],20*sizeof(char));

  puts("enter a name");
  gets((*p)[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  printf("cnt=%d\n",cnt);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In main, all you do is to assign `p = NULL` and then use this NULL pointer in `print`, which causes the segfault. Note that `add(p)` is equivalent to `add(NULL)` and does not change `p`.
Did you mean to pass an address with `add(&p)`? If so, you need to fiddle a bit with the number of `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass by reference. You need to pass the address of your pointer to make sure the changes in function `add()` is reflected in `main()`. Avoid using `gets()`

In this case

```
add(&p);
```

Accordingly your `add()` function definition should change to handle this.
Or the other way is for the add function to make the required allocations and return that address to your pointer

```
char **add();
```

Check the code below:

```
char  **add(char **p)
{
  int i;
  p=(char**)realloc(p,(cnt+1)*sizeof(char*));
  if(p==NULL)
  {
        printf("Error: memory not available\n");
        return;

  }
  p[cnt]=NULL;
  p[cnt]=(char*)realloc(p[cnt],20*sizeof(char));

  scanf("%s",p[cnt]);
  cnt++;
  printf("cnt=%d\n",cnt);
  return p;
}
```

So your call should be:

```
p = add(p);
```

Answer (score 0):

A copy of 2D pointer p is created in the add function, and updating this pointer will not be reflected  in the main function.
A quick solution to this problem is to return the 2D pointer 'p' from the add function.

```
char** print(char **p)
{
    ....
    ....
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other things, I don't think anyone's mentioned the `realloc` trap of reallocation failure. Suppose this call

```
p=(char**)realloc(p,(cnt+1)*sizeof(char*));
```

fails to allocate the new memory: what happens then? Yes, you will get `NULL` returned: but the memory which **was** allocated, and which `p`is pointing to, does **not** get `free`'d. Instant memory leak.

You **must** call `realloc` like this:

```
char* pTemp = realloc(p, cnt + 1);
if(pTemp != NULL)
{
    p = pTemp;             // Now safe to update p
}
else
{
    // Error handling as required, possibly including freeing p
}
```

Yet another reason **not** to use `realloc`. It doesn't really by you very much over doing the buffer copies yourself IMHO.